Fail to start VM in headless mode on windows
On windows 10 22H2, i can't sart VM in headless mode. I can't work with Ansible & Molecule on my laptop (Enterprise).
I reproduce the error with this command :
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox> .\VBoxManage.exe startvm Test --type=headless

VBoxManage.exe: error: The virtual machine 'Test' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code -1073741819 (0xc0000005)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine

I'm looking for fix it since 3 weeks, i don't know how to do it. It works in GUI mode ...
I have an admin account.
Any idea to fix this ?

have you searched for that error? There seems to be a bit of talk about some anti virus programs causing this, or enabling 3D/2D acceleration as a cause, or "VirtualBox Hardening Issues"

Computer has SentinelOne Agent, but when i'm starting VM in headless mode I haven't any log message in sentinelone client..

SentinelOne - yeah, that one comes up a bit in google ... you didn't address the other two possibilities though -   or enabling 3D/2D acceleration as a cause (i.e. disable it), or "VirtualBox Hardening Issues" - look it up

I tried with System>Acceleration>Paravirtualization Interface>None, it doesn't work anymore, I always get the same message when I start the VM in headless mode ...
I tried my configuration on another laptop (same model as the first one) but it's outside the domain, it's running basic windows 10 and my configuration works fine.

I haven't used VirtualBox in a while, so I'm not familiar with System>Acceleration>Paravirtualization Interface if that even relates to anything I said

I found the problem component in my POC, it was S1 (Sentinel One). It didn't block Virtual Box, but the simple fact that it scanned VboxHeadless was a problem.
